# Deploying a Windows Phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have Developed a small windows Phone 7 app, for our customer[in INDIA]. The Problem is we are giving it free like a goodie for our main site. Is there any way to Upload the app into an Windows Phone without Uploading it to the market place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put an app on a phone without going through the marketplace, the phone has to be 'developer unlocked'. Once that is done, you can distribute your .xap file to the customer, and they can transfer the file to any developer unlocked phone. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/publicsector/archive/2011/01/04/unlock-your-windows-phone-7-for-development.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To 'Developer Unlock' you need a developer account. And 'Developer unlocking' each user's phone is practically very difficult.

Instead I would suggest you to upload your app to marketplace and share the marketplace link in your site or mail the link to your users.

Comment: Tor further this, you can "deep link" to your app in the marketplace. It'll be published, but not discoverable through any interface (marketplace app on phone, desktop Zune software, marketplace in web browser). The only way to download and install it is with the link as nkchandra said.